# Splat [0.3.4] on Xamarin.iOS: issues with RectangleF and PointF

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to embrace the new PCL fun on a Xamarin.iOS project in Xamarin Studio. I created a PCL "Core" library for my project and added [Splat](https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat) ([v0.3.4](https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat/releases/tag/0.3.4)) via NuGet. Then, in a consuming iOS project, I reference my core library. Once I do that, a couple compile errors show up.

One of these:

```
Error CS0012: The type `System.Drawing.PointF' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly `Splat.Portable, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' (CS0012)
```

Multiple of these:

```
Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Drawing.PointF [monotouch, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]' to `System.Drawing.PointF [Splat.Portable, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]' (CS0029)
```

It looks like this was addressed in an [pull request to Splat](https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat/pull/29) that landed since v0.3.4 hit NuGet. Following along with the notes there, I added a reference to `Splat.Portable.dll` to the iOS project. When I do, the compile errors change up to complain about too many type definitions.

```
Error CS0433: The imported type `System.Drawing.RectangleF' is defined multiple times (CS0433)
Error CS0433: The imported type `System.Drawing.PointF' is defined multiple times (CS0433)
```

Is it possible to work around these errors using Xamarin Studio 4.2.1 (Xamarin.iOS 7.0.4.209), and Splat 0.3.4 or do I need to build the latest code with its type-forwarding awesomeness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, I'll build a new release of Splat tomorrow'ish, but building from source will also solve this.

**Edit:** Splat 1.0 is live and contains the fix for this bug

Comment: Hi Paul, I just installed Splat today (actually it got installed with Akavache) and I'm having this error. Splat version is 1.3.3 on iOS. Do you know of any solution? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Update Splat to the last version (1.6.2) - Splat 1.3.3 still have this issue.